# How to incrementally increase all tuples within the same dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, pygame, tuples

I have a dictionary which generates a "map" 
e.g. tuple (x, y) : mapTile

```
mapGenCode = {(1, 1): 0, (2, 1): 1, (3, 1): 0, (1, 2): 0, (2, 2): 2, (3, 2): 1}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when an keyboard arrow is pushed all the x/y values within the same dictionary are incremented by +1/-1

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_loc = x_loc-1
            x_map -1

mapRefresh(x_map, y_map)

def mapRefresh(x, y):

    if x == -1:
        for (key1, key2), value in mapGenCode.iteritems():
            newkeyX = key1 -1
            mapGenCode[newKey1, key2] = value
```

I have previously run into this error

```
runtimeerror: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: try recreating the `dict` instead of updating it.

Comment: tupples are [immutable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-tuple), so a dict of tuples might not be the best way to keep this info.

Comment: How do you suggest I recreate it and given the fact I'll be changing it every time i push an arrow key will it work?

Comment: won't Class be easier, which keeps a coordinate, the values and the movement methods?

Comment: I think you would get better answers, if you described your goals (what you actually want to achieve in your game) more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "for key, value in dic", you can consider following code

```
while key in dic:
    func()
    key += 1
```